# Aggregating data in Python using more than one measure from a formula

Tags: python, aggregation

Suppose I have a series of data that I want to aggregate by Cat

```
Cat   Volume   Result

A      45      4
A      57      3
B      56      3
C      45      1
C      55      2
```

I would like to aggregate variance, Skewness and Kurtosis of volume and maximum of Result by cat. I know how to do it one by one by calculating the variance, skewness and Kurtosis of volume but I would like to it neatly   with something like this

```
def f(row):
    row['ResultM']=row['Result'].max()
    row['Variance'] = pd.DataFrame(scipy.stats.moment(row['Volume'], moment=[2,3,4]))
return 

TestData=OrgData.groupby('Id').apply(f)
```

But it does not work . Can anyone   offer suggestions how I can correct my code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Edit

```
def f(x):
    df = pd.DataFrame(scipy.stats.moment(x.Volume.astype(int),moment=[2,3,4]),index=['var','skew','kurtosis']).T
    df['result_max'] = x.Result.astype(int).max()
    return df

df.groupby('Cat').apply(f)
```

Let's try this:

```
from scipy import stats

OrgData.groupby('Cat').agg({'Result':'max','Volume':[stats.skew,np.var,stats.kurtosis]})
```

Output:

```
    Result Volume               
       max   skew   var kurtosis
Cat                             
A        4      0  72.0       -2
B        3      0   NaN       -3
C        2      0  50.0       -2
```

Comment: Thanks. I know that would work but I was hoping to use this function

scipy.stats.moment(row['Volume'], moment=[2,3,4]))

so I can capture all moments without having to key in one by one as I have to do it for a lot of variables

Comment: @user44137  Okay, I modified the code to look use stats.moment.  You were really close with your original code.

Comment: Thanks but the data is in long form when I want it in wide form. I tried this but it does not work


def f(x):
    df=pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(scipy.stats.moment(x.Volume,moment=[2,3,4])),columns=['var','skew','kurtosis'])
    #df['Result']=x.Result.max()
    return df

Comment: Can you paste a copy of your expected output in the question?